# An algebra $A$ vanishes nowhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

[image]What it means : "The algebra A vanishes nowhere" ?

Is it equivalent to say: "The algebra A has unity 1 " ?

Note: I'm taking a course of Analysis and the concept come up in the proof of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: It does sound like something that might come up in the S-W theorem. But as it stands I can't figure out what it means. Can you please give a little more context, for instance a slightly longer quotation featuring this phrase?

Comment: Probably refers to a subalgebra of continuous real (or complex) valued functions on a topological space $X$. In that case, it most likely means that for any $x\in X, \exists f\in A$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've edited my question. Is it enough? Also If you have Real Analysis book by Pugh you can find it in.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan and the fact that for any x is in X , there exist f in A such that f(x)≠0 is equivalent to say that 1 is in A?